# Control git push through git hook

Tags: git

I want to prevent git push after said time say 2018-04-14 00:00 for all the repos our team is using by writing short script as part of. /git/hooks/prepush. Now I want the push to be enabled say after two days. For that I have to again change the hook. Is it any better way than that.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're trying to accomplish. What is your goal? Why are you trying to prevent pushing after a particular time and re-enable it at a later time?

Comment: Also, hooks are per-repository. If you want to "globally" control something like this you'll have to do it on your shared remote. You probably don't want a pre-push hook there; a pre-receive hook is more appropriate.

Comment: As per requirement of our team no code push would be done beyond every alternate Friday 6 pm and enable again by Tuesday. This is for all repos.

Answer (score 1):

A better approach is to centralized the hook, with a [server-side hook](https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#_server_side_hooks), if you have access and control over the Git repositories hosting server.

Then a pre-receive hook could check the date/time, and reject the push.

In the same approach, an authorization layer like [gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/) proposes a similar mechanism: [restricting by day of week](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/cookbook/#example-1-restricting-by-day-of-week) (which can be adapted to your case).